# Why won't my function return variable values and update them in python?

Tags: python

I am building a nutrition calculator, and the function below is the toppings function that updates the macro variables with whatever toppings you choose from the toppings_list.

```
def f_toppings(fiveguys_toppings, calories, carbs, protein, total_fat, sat_fat, trans_fat, sodium, sugar, fiber):
    toppings_list = ['A1 Sauce', 'barbeque', 'green pepper', 'grilled mushrooms', 'hot sauce', 'jalapenos', 'ketchup', 'lettuce', 'mayo', 'mustard', 'onions', 'pickles', 'relish', 'tomatoes']
    while True:
        burger_toppings = input(f"The toppings available are:\n{toppings_list}\nWhat toppings do you want? Please be specific to the spelling listed. \nIf you don't want toppings or are finished, leave the response blank and presss enter:\n\n")

        if not burger_toppings:

            return calories, carbs, protein, total_fat, sat_fat, trans_fat, sodium, sugar, fiber

        elif burger_toppings not in fiveguys_toppings:
            print(f"{burger_toppings.capitalize()} is not one of the options!")
            continue

        calories += fiveguys_toppings[burger_toppings][0]
        carbs += fiveguys_toppings[burger_toppings][1]
        protein += fiveguys_toppings[burger_toppings][2]
        total_fat += fiveguys_toppings[burger_toppings][3]
        sat_fat += fiveguys_toppings[burger_toppings][4]
        trans_fat += fiveguys_toppings[burger_toppings][5]
        sodium += fiveguys_toppings[burger_toppings][6]
        sugar += fiveguys_toppings[burger_toppings][7]
        fiber += fiveguys_toppings[burger_toppings][8]
        toppings_list.remove(burger_toppings)
        print(calories, carbs, protein, total_fat, sat_fat, trans_fat, sodium, sugar, fiber)
```

This function is used in the main fiveguys function shown below.

```
def fiveguys():
    calories = None
    carbs = None
    protein = None
    total_fat = None
    sat_fat = None
    trans_fat = None
    sodium = None
    sugar = None
    fiber = None
    fiveguys_menu = {'burger': {'hamburger':[700, 39, 39, 43, 19.5, 2, 430, 8, 2], 'cheeseburger':[770, 39, 43, 49, 23.5, 2.2, 790, 8, 2], 'baconburger':[780, 39, 43, 50, 22.5, 2, 690, 8, 2 ], 'baconcheeseburger': [850, 39, 47, 56, 26.5, 2.2, 1050, 8, 2 ]},'fries': {'smallfries':[526, 72, 8, 23, 4, .5, 531, 2, 8], 'regularfries':[953, 131, 15, 41, 7, 1, 962, 4, 15], 'largefries':[1314, 181, 20, 57, 10, 1, 1327, 6, 20]}}
    # Calories, Carbs, Protein, Total Fat, Saturated Fat, Trans Fat, Sodium, Sugars, Fiber
    fiveguys_toppings = {'A1 Sauce':[15, 3, 0, 0, 0,0, 280, 2, 0], 'barbeque':[60, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 10, 0], 'green pepper':[5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 'grilled mushrooms':[5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55, 1, 0], 'hot sauce':[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0], 'jalapenos':[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'ketchup':[20, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 160, 4, 0], 'lettuce':[4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0], 'mayo':[100, 0, 0, 11, 2, 0, 75, 0, 0], 'mustard':[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 0], 'onions':[10, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], 'pickles':[3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'relish':[10 , 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 105, 3, 0], 'tomatoes':[9, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0]}


    while True:
        food = input("What're you tryna eat?  Please state whether you want a burger or fries, fatty.\n").lower().replace(" ", "")
        if 'burger' in food:
            while True:
                burger_type = input('Out of a hamburger, cheeseburger, baconburger, and bacon cheeseburger, which one do you want?\n').lower().replace(" ", "")
                if 'ham' in burger_type:
                    calories = fiveguys_menu['burger']['hamburger'][0]
                    carbs = fiveguys_menu['burger']['hamburger'][1]
                    protein = fiveguys_menu['burger']['hamburger'][2]
                    total_fat = fiveguys_menu['burger']['hamburger'][3]
                    sat_fat = fiveguys_menu['burger']['hamburger'][4]
                    trans_fat = fiveguys_menu['burger']['hamburger'][5]
                    sodium = fiveguys_menu['burger']['hamburger'][6]
                    sugar = fiveguys_menu['burger']['hamburger'][7]
                    fiber = fiveguys_menu['burger']['hamburger'][8]
                    print_message("One hamburger coming up.")
                    f_toppings(fiveguys_toppings, calories, carbs, protein, total_fat, sat_fat, trans_fat, sodium, sugar, fiber)
                    print(calories, carbs, protein, total_fat, sat_fat, trans_fat, sodium, sugar, fiber)
                    print_message(f"\nYour meal contains:\n{calories} calories \n{carbs} grams of carbs \n{protein} grams of protein \n{total_fat} grams of total fat \n{sat_fat} grams of saturated fat \n{trans_fat} grams of trans fat \n{sodium} milligrams of sodium \n{sugar} grams of sugar \n{fiber} grams of fiber\n")
                    return calories, carbs, protein, total_fat, sat_fat, trans_fat, sodium, sugar, fiber
```

However, in the last print_message, the macro variables revert back to the pre toppings variables, even though I returned the updated variables from the f_toppings function.  Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you post your output?

Comment: You never used the return value, so what do you expect? If I define `def f(x): x += 1 ... return x` and I start with `x = 5` then calling `f(x)` and doing nothing with the return value will *not* transform `x` from `5` to `6`, though `x = f(x)` will change `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are not returning anything from f_toppings() function if its in toppings_list and printing old values only.

Add below line of code at the end of f_toppings() function:

```
return calories, carbs, protein, total_fat, sat_fat, trans_fat, sodium, sugar, fiber
```

receive it in fiveguys function as following:

```
calories, carbs, protein, total_fat, sat_fat, trans_fat, sodium, sugar, fiber = f_toppings(fiveguys_toppings, calories, carbs, protein, total_fat, sat_fat, trans_fat, sodium, sugar, fiber)
```

Comment: `f_toppings` has a `return` statement (though the execution path is somewhat convoluted before you get there) but you are correct that OP needs to do something to get those return values in the calling function.

Comment: `f_toppings` has an infinite loop which is only broken when its current return statement is reached. Putting a return statement after that loop would be superfluous since you would never reach the return statement that you suggest.

Comment: Yes,I agree the function is will never reach return statement since there is "continue" in elif.